# XML element holds non xml elements (not wrapped in cdata)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using simple xml for php and trying to parse the `<content>` element that is a part of following tree:

`<entry>`

...`<title>`

...`<link>`

...`<summary>`

...`<content>`

The problem is that `<content>` element cannot be read as a string because it has "non string" content that is not wrapped in CDATA:

```
<content type="xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" xml:base="...">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p><strong>text... text...</strong> text <a     href="..." 
target="_self">LINK</a>. text</p>
</content>
```

I use the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed_uri);
```

and then:

```
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
$item = new RSSItem();
$item->title = (string) $entry->title;
$item->content = (string)$entry->content;
$item->date = (string) $entry->published;
```

My content member var is empty. The others are as expected
If I change *$item->content = (string)$entry->content;* to *$item->content = $entry-*>content; then I get another object nested in *$item->content* variable

Any ide how to force parser not to interpret elements found in content element (div, p etc.) as nested elements?

Thanks in advance,
L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$entry->content->asXML()`.

See http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml

Comment: I love you!!! :)))) Thanks... It works and now I'm trying to understand this magic method...